# SharePoint JSON tileProps breaks formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, conditional, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am attempting to troubleshoot a formatting issue with JSON and actually found a Microsoft example that has the same problem for me. I developed a list using the same column names as the code below:

```
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "tileProps": {
    "height": "250",
    "width": "350",
    "hideSelection": true,
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "align-items": "stretch",
        "margin-bottom": "16px",
        "min-width": "150px",
        "flex-grow": "1",
        "justify-content": "space-around",
        "padding": "5px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "width": "95%",
            "height": "92%",
            "box-shadow": "0px 1.6px 3.6px 0 #00000024, 0px 0.3px 0.9px 0 #00000024",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "border-radius": "2px",
            "padding-left": "16px",
            "padding-top": "16px"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLighterAlt"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "text-align": "left"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "color":"#333333",
                    "font-size": "16px",
                    "font-weight":"600",
                    "margin-bottom":"5px"
                },
                  "txtContent": "[$Title]"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "color":"#333333",
                    "font-size": "14px",
                    "line-height":"1.8"
                },
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-listPadding"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[$Feedback]"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "button",
                  "customRowAction": {
                    "action": "defaultClick"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "Give feedback",
                  "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-button"
                  },
                  "style": {
                    "display": {
                      "operator": "?",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "==",
                          "operands": [
                            "@me",
                            "[$Assigned_x0020_To.email]"
                          ]
                        },
                        "",
                        "none"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However I am not getting this nice flex box look:
[image: List items show horizontally]

It simply breaks the JSON code and doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing? I feel like it might be something glaringly obvious but after a day and a half of staring, I think I'm too close to the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This view formatting only works in the Tiles view.

[image]

The format expects the **Title** field

The format expects a text column with an **internal name** of **Feedback**

The format expects a person column with an **internal name** of **Assigned_x0020_To**

If you want to works in the List view, we can use the formatting below.

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-row-card"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "text-align": "left"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-row-title"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$Title]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-row-listPadding"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$Feedback]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "button",
            "customRowAction": {
              "action": "defaultClick"
            },
            "txtContent": "Give feedback",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-row-button"
            },
            "style": {
              "display": {
                "operator": "?",
                "operands": [
                  {
                    "operator": "==",
                    "operands": [
                      "@me",
                      "[$Assigned_x0020_To.email]"
                    ]
                  },
                  "",
                  "none"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I told you it would be some stupidly glaringly obvious reason!! Thank you so much.